# Google API redirect URL to my localhost

Tags: google-api

My application work with Google API. After authentication, it directs the response to redirect URL.

Can i redirect response to my local URL so that i can test my application.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Have you found out a solution?

Comment: same issue...after EditPassword page i want to redirect to my application...

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053381/google-api-how-to-redirect-url-to-my-localhost/16924836#16924836